# How to pass in the context of a Class Based View to the Template in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a script in Django where all users can view the profile of another user. I am able to get an answer regarding my question about CBV ListView with the get_queryset method. I am now able to access the profile of another user, but I am not able to pass it into my home template.

**View.py**

```
class OtherUserProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Post
    template_name = "core/otheruser.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=self.kwargs['user_id'])
        return queryset
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('profile/<int:user_id>/', OtherUserProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

In the View.py, I used the ListView and the get_queryset method. I passed in the user_id so I can access all the objects of another user.

**Home.html**

```
{% extends "core/base.html" %}

{% block content%}
{% for item in object_list%}
<div class="container">
<div class="card text-light bg-secondary mb-3 mx-auto" style="max-width: 60rem;">
    <div class="card-header text-light">{{item.title}}</div>
    <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text text-light">{{item.content}}</p>
    <h6 class="card-title text-light"><a class="text-light" href="{% url 'core:detail' item.pk %}">Full Page</a></h6>
    <p class="card-text text-light"><a class="text-light " href="{% url 'core:profile' user_id=view.kwargs.user_id %}">{{item.user}}</a><small class="text-light"> {{item.created}} </small></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

However, when I tried to passed in the script `<a class="text-light " href="{% url 'core:profile' user_id=view.kwargs.user_id %}">{{item.user}}</a>`, I got an error message

**NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'profile' with keyword arguments '{'user_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$']**

Comment: Try `item.user_id`: `{% url 'core:profile' user_id=item.user_id %}`

Comment: Cool!! It actually works. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `get_context_data` method to the view

[Learn more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context)